# Hidden model-bound values in view not getting passed to controller when populated manually

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using the KendoUI AutoComplete for a number of look-ups on a custom editor template that pop-ups off a grid for new rows and edits.  The Kendo AutoComplete does have a DataTextField property and does not DataValueField property like a DropDownList would.  So, I found I am able to get the Value of the selected item in the AutoComplete with a little Javascript and iterrogating the "dataItem" object in the select handler.  And I put that value into a "SelectedID" field declared with @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.*SelectedID*) on the select event.

Now, when I do a save from the view and have a break point on my controller action that captures the incoming model, all those ID values where i set the value manually are empty/null/blank.   I've checked the DO and have done "console.log" to read out the values of the hidden fields before the post and the values are populated.  I've changed the datatypes (strings, guids, etc) and I've changed the Html Helper type as well from a HiddenFor to a EditorFor just to make sure the values are indeed there.

So i think this is a problem when the values of an element that are part of the model are populated in a "manual" fashion.  The text of the AutoCompletes comes through if I bind that to a field on the model as well.  Any date fields, checkboxes and free-form text fields come through as well.  It seems it is just values of model bound fields where I set the values manually that don't make it over the "wire".   Any thoughts?  Solutions?  I know the Selected Value is accessible ... it's just a matter of properly getting it into the "HiddenFor" fields.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Find a solution by using the Select2 jQuery plugin. (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)   It fits in well, visually, with an application that is full of other KendoUI stuff.